# Сhange checkbox to select

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to change this so that you can choose not through a checkbox but through select

```
$("input[name=koleso]:first").prop("checked", true);
    $('body').on('click', '.koleso label', function (e) {
        koleso = $('.koleso input#'+$(this).attr('for')).data('koleso');
        calc();
    });
```

html

```
<div class="radiosBl koleso clearfix">
                    <input type="radio" checked name="koleso" id="kol_4" value="4" data-koleso="0">
                    <label for="kol_4"><span>ALL</span></label>
                    <input type="radio" name="koleso" id="kol_3" value="3" data-koleso="1">
                    <label for="kol_3"><span>3</span></label>
                    <input type="radio" name="koleso" id="kol_2" value="2" data-koleso="2">
                    <label for="kol_2"><span>2</span></label>
                    <input type="radio" name="koleso" id="kol_1" value="1" data-koleso="3">
                    <label for="kol_1"><span>1</span></label>
                    <input type="radio" name="koleso" id="kol_0" value="0" data-koleso="4">
                    <label for="kol_0"><span>NO</span></label>
                </div>
```

Comment: You mean, binding click event to `select` not `.koleso label`?

Comment: I need to do so, what I now select through the checkbox. Redo what I would choose through select

Comment: Please can you elaborate more on your issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want to convert group checkbox to select

```
    <div class="radiosBl koleso clearfix">
        <select>
            <option value="4" data-koleso="0">ALL</option>
            <option value="3" data-koleso="1">3</option>
            <option value="2" data-koleso="2">2</option>
            <option value="1" data-koleso="3">1</option>
            <option value="0" data-koleso="4">NO</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

```
        $("input[name=koleso]:first").prop("checked", true);
        $('body').on('change', '.koleso select', function (e) {
            koleso = $(this).children("option:selected").data("koleso");
            calc();
        });
```